# How to configure AD so that users who travel to different sites have the same Desktop and My Documents folders

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs, user-profile

I am settings up my Windows 2008 Active Directory environment so that users can travel between 2 sites and still access their Desktop and My Documents folders.

Currently, we have 2 sites (Site A and Site B).  Site A has been in existence for about a year and a half.

Now, we are adding Site B, which has Server B. Site A and Site B are connected via VPN. I don't know the exact speed of the VPN but one location has 4Mbit symmetric broadband and the other has 100Mbit Fibre broadband.

We opted to have a server in each location in the event that the VPN connection or Internet connection went down.

Site A and Site B both have their own OUs.

I already have a GPO for folder redirection at the OU level, which has been working well at Site A.

I would like User 1 from Site A to be able to go to Site B and login to one of the desktops and be able to see their desktop and my documents folders the same way they see them when they login to their desktop at Site A.

What do I have to do to make this work? I have read up on DFS, but there seems to be no clear "how to" on the supported way to get it working.

I found this technote:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533009

and this blog post, which seems to discourage setting this up.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/09/01/microsoft-s-support-statement-around-replicated-user-profile-data.aspx

Comment: I'm almost inclined to close as exact duplicate with: http://serverfault.com/questions/414112/site-specific-folder-redirection-through-group-policy

Answer (score -3):

Setup a shared locked down folder and use the UNC path with a variable in the name \\server\path\%username% in the group policy folder redirection settings. We tie this into a U drive (\\server\path\%username%) which has has sub-directories, i.e. Desktop, My Documents etc

Comment: If you use the \\servernameA in the path then when they go to Site B, the group policy redirects to the ServernameA in site A.